# C# Leap year check

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a program that shows the amount of days in a month, and I need to add leap years, so I've asked for the year and the way I'm trying to figure out the leap year is to check if the year is a multiple of 4, it says that it "cannot take the address of the given expression". Here is my code:

```
 if (month == 2)
      Console.WriteLine("\nThere are 28 days in Febuary");

 if (month == 2) &(4%year);
      Console.WriteLine("\nThere are 29 days in Febuary this year as it is a leap year");
```

Comment: Well, use [`DateTime.GetDaysInMonth`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth(v=vs.110).aspx) ;-)

Comment: Click [edit] if you want to edit your code

Comment: Please don't add unrelated tags.

Comment: haha very funny XD unfortunately i need to hand this in XD

Comment: i didnt mean to add that sorry

Comment: Don't forget rules for centuries - not all multiples of four are leap years

Comment: [MS](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,3c149093001ab007,references) uses this to check a leap-year: `year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0);`

Comment: Don't try to implement your own version when there is one in the standard library! (Sometimes tasks like this are given as exercises. That's ok, just don't use them in real life.)

Comment: I assume that this is homework, so you must write your own method (and not just use `DateTime.IsLeapYear(int year)`. Your check for leap year will work for years from 2001 until 2099, but it will fail at 2100. [Wikipedia gives the correct algorithm to use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm). Note that boolean `and` in C# is written as `&&`, not as `&`, which is where your compile error is coming from.

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
DateTime.IsLeapYear(year)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question.

Comment: There is no question.
I gave this suggestion based on the titel "C# Leap year check" and 
"and I need to add leap years, so I've asked for the year and the way I'm trying to figure out the leap year is to check...".

So why not use functions that are already given?

Comment: @TheSkimek: well, alwas also read the body of a question before answering. OP wants to "make a program that shows the amount of days in a month". The leap-year check is only part of the question. But OP's issue is the "cannot take the address of the given expression" error.

Comment: Yes he wants to make a program. For me it doesnt sound like thats where he has the problem thought. He knows how to get there. The problem is more "figure out the leap year" part.

Anyway. I dont think there is much point in discussing further, as there are enough answers already from which OP can pick the one that suits him best

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax for your second if is totally incorrect here. First, adding a `;` at the end of the if condition means that you are simply doing nothing after checking your condition. Second, you used the [& operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/and-operator) which returns the address of an operand, leading to the error you just had. You wanted to use the [&& operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-and-operator) here. Finally, just set your whole condition in the same pair of parenthesis.

Also, make sure to check about what is exactly a leap year. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Gregorian_calendar):

> Every year that is exactly divisible by four is a leap year, except for years that are exactly divisible by 100, but these centurial years are leap years if they are exactly divisible by 400. For example, the years 1700, 1800, and 1900 were not leap years, but the years 1600 and 2000 were.

In the end, your corrected if would give:

```
if (month == 2 && year % 4==0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0))
    Console.WriteLine("\nThere are 29 days in Febuary this year as it is a leap year");
```

Comment: @FredEnator: remember to accept the answer that helped you most

Comment: Note that using a single & in your _"corrected"_ code would work equally as well - for boolean expression single & computes the logical AND of the operands. _"if (month == 2 & year % 4==0 & (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0))
"_

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the code as follows:

```
if (month == 2 && DateTime.IsLeapYear(year))
    Console.WriteLine("\nThere are 29 days in Febuary this year as it is a leap year");
else if (month == 2)
    Console.WriteLine("\nThere are 28 days in Febuary");
```

What was changed?

- You had a semi-colon at the end of the second if statement
- Move the month == 2 as the second if statement, as it will always enter the first if when month is February
- Use else if, else it will enter both if statements and write down the two statements

(Added suggestions from @waka and @TheSkimek, thanks!)

Comment: i see thank you very much everyone i see what i did now thanks :)

Comment: `year % 4 == 0` will give the wrong answer for years like 2100, which is not a leap year. Use one of the many libraries out there, don't try to reinvent the wheel...

Answer (score 0):

The correct code you need to determine a leap year is:

```
if (month == 2)
{
    if ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nThere are 29 days in Febuary this year as it is a leap year");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nThere are 28 days in Febuary");
    }
}
```

Leap years occur on year divisible by 4 unless they are divisible by 100 unless they are divisible by 400.